# Localizing array and other special values in the Settings bundle

Tags: ios, localization, settings, plist, bundle

I'm looking for a way to localize different strings of the Settings.bundle in iOS. While localizing regular strings is straight-forward, I wonder if and how you would localize:

1. **Arrays**. Consider the following plist entry:

   ```
   <dict>
     <key>DefaultValue</key>
     <string>Schedules</string>
     <key>Key</key>
     <string>defaultView</string>
     <key>Title</key>
     <string>Default View</string>
     <key>Titles</key>
     <array>
       <string>Schedules</string>
       <string>Tasks</string>
       <string>Patients</string>
       <string>Links</string>
     </array>
     <key>Type</key>
     <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
     <key>Values</key>
     <array>
       <string>Schedules</string>
       <string>Tasks</string>
       <string>Patients</string>
       <string>Links</string>
     </array>
   </dict>
   ```

   To localize the title, I add

   ```
   "Default View" = "Translated Default View";
   ```

   to the Root.strings file. But how can I get the Titles of the PSMultiValueSpecifier translated?
2. **FooterText**.
   Is it possible to translate the *FooterText* of the following entry?

   ```
   <dict>
     <key>Title</key>
     <string>Server Settings</string>
     <key>Type</key>
     <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
     <key>FooterText</key>
     <string>Can this text be translated?</string>
   </dict>
   ```

Comment: `"Can this text be translated?" = "Est-ce que ce texte peut etre traduit?"` should do the trick.

Comment: This indeed does the trick for the `FooterText`, thank you. Any update for the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my app, I have simply added the Titles strings/translations to Root.strings:

```
"Schedules" = "Translated Schedules";
"Patients" = "Translated Patients";
```

and so on, works as expected.